# Android HttpURLConnection working in debug mode, but not when released on the playstore

Tags: android

I am using `HttpURLConnection` to create an `InputStream` to determine if a file is available online or not. It works spot on in the debug mode, installed directly from Android Studio, but when I download the app (same code, apk etc), it doesn't work! Very strange!

Has anyone else experienced this, or know of a solution?

My HttpURLConnection code is:

```
URL url = null;
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
try {
    url = new URL("http://www.websiteurl.co.uk/app/" + databaseName + "/data.csv");
} catch (MalformedURLException error) {}
try {
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    try {
        if (reader.readLine() != null) {
            setupAvailable = true;
        } else {
            setupAvailable = false;
        }
    }
    finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
} catch (IOException error) {}
        finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
```

Comment: Do you have any logs when it doesn’t work? You’d better print your exceptions.

Comment: I don't have any exceptions, as I'm not experiencing a runtime error. A button is either able to be clicked or it is disabled, depending on the result. On the play store version, it doesn't work, but in the debug version, it does.

Comment: I see in your code you have exceptions handled and not printed, try to print them and upload it to play store again and see what it prints. It can not just “doesn’t work”, it should throw exception, return bad response or whatever else. Also you check if line is not null - you’d rather print that line to see what it returns as well as the status code if your response.

Comment: Ahh yes! I removed these as I was using the Log tool, and before I could release the version, android told me to remove all Log references for the release version. How do I print them? Thanks for your help

Comment: `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: The strange nature continues! Simply applying the `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch statements made it work! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Simply applying the e.printStackTrace() in the catch statements made it work! I guess it didn't like the empty catch statements!